# Automatic Date Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script to automatically advance dates in a spreadsheet by one. Is there any way to do this?

For example, in our spreadsheet, we may have 4 different dates that need to advance by one.

```
2/17/2017

2/14/2017

2/15/2017

2/18/2017.
```

Basically everytime I want to run this script, I want all dates in a spreadsheet to advance by one. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far. You can't expect other to write code for you. That is how you learn brother.

Comment: it's quite unclear, do you want a script that cycles through a dates in a spreadsheet range or a script that inserts dates in a sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this with some financial data and it appears to work okay. It runs fairly fast.

If you want all of the dates in the spreadsheet then the first line of incrDate should be

```
var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
```

and I just went back and tested that as well.

This is the entire code for the code.gs file including menu. So you may want to doctor it up a bit.

I was a fun problem.  Actually the hardest part was figuring out the isDate function. 
Thanks

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Range Tools')
      .addItem('Increment A Date by one day','incrDate')
      .addToUi();
};

function incrDate()
{
    var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(); // current selection
  var rngA = rng.getValues();
  if(rng.getNumRows() > 1 && rng.getNumColumns() > 1) // two dimension array
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < rngA.length; i++)
    {
      for(var j =0; j < rngA[i].length;j++)
      {

        if(isDate(rngA[i][j]))
        {
          rngA[i][j] = new Date(rngA[i][j].getTime() + (1 * 86400000));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(rng.getNumRows() > 1 && rng.getNumColumns() == 1) //single column
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < rngA.length ; i++)
    {
      if(isDate(rngA[i][0]))
      {
        rngA[i][0] = new Date(rngA[i][0].getTime() + (1 * 86400000));
      }
    }

  }
    if(rng.getNumRows() == 1 && rng.getNumColumns() > 1)//single row
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < rngA[0].length ; i++)
    {
      if(isDate(rngA[0][i]))
      {
        rngA[0][i] = new Date(rngA[0][i].getTime() + (1 * 86400000));
      }
    }
  }
  if(rng.getNumRows() == 1 && rng.getNumColumns() == 1) //single cell
  {
    if(isDate(rngA[0][0]))
    {
      rngA[0][0] = new Date(rngA[0][0].getTime() + (1 * 86400000));
    }
  }
  rng.setValues(rngA);
}

function isDate (x)  
{ 
  return (null != x) && !isNaN(x) && ("undefined" !== typeof x.getDate); 
}
```

Comment: Glad to be of some help.  It was a fun little project especially the isDate() function.  Come on back if you need any more help.

Comment: Hey Cooper quick question, when I run the formula it asks for permission to edit and view documents in Google Drive.

Comment: When I go to my next file it asks again, any thoughts? I constantly do this to  different files so each time I do this it asks for another permission when I had already given it access.

Comment: This is something I'm not very familiar with.  I'll research it a little but a cursory examination suggests that placing this in a comment may do the trick.  /**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

Comment: Hi Cooper, sorry to bother you again! For some reason, when I run this script, it deletes ALL of the formulas in the spreadsheet. Do you know why this may be happening?

Comment: You're correct.  I hadn't tried running it on a spreadsheet that had formulas and since you wanted to do it for entire spreadsheet I used the datarange and getValues and setValues.  The simple solution is to restrict the range that this function is applied to.  I typically don't use formulas in cells.  Instead I just do all my calculations in arrays and then setValues all at one time.  Sorry about that.  I'm learning too.

Comment: var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("D2:D79"); basically like so? What if I wanted to add another range such as E81:E92 how would I add that 2nd range?

Comment: You could probably use named ranges like DateChange1 DateChange2 and such.  Then you could use the function sheet.getNamedRanges which returns all of the names ranges in the as an array and you could loop through them making sure that they met some criteria like matching a regular express similar to /^DateChange\d+/ that way if there are any other named ranges created they would not be subjected to this function.   I hope this helps let me know how it goes.